# Use a Video Card (GeForce 9800GT) and a AMD 5150 processor with Radeon R3

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a [GeForce 9800GT](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9800gt) video card, I use it for over a year with my old Intel powered machine. But my processor died so I bought a new processor ([APU AMD Athlon 5150](http://www.amd.com/es-es/products/processors/desktop/athlon)) and a new MB ([ASRock AM1B-M](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AM1B-M/)).

Everything good, but my video card is not recognized, the fan is spinning and all.

I tried to install its drivers but my OS's (Windows and Ubuntu) didn't recognized it. I checked that the card was correctly installed. So I have some questions:

1. The integrated Radeon in the CPU makes impossible to have a video card?
2. Is there a way to disable the integrated GPU? I tried in the BIOS with no luck.
3. Is there a way to use dual monitors with another hardware?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: PCI Info:
[image: PCI]

Comment: Did you attach a 12V Lane Connector to it?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness yes sir, the fan is spinning

Comment: What happened when you went to change the Primary Graphics Adapter in BIOS?

Comment: @Ayan the computer is the same with or without the card. I tested it in another computer and is ok. When I changed that to Onboard and/or PCI Express, nothing happened. :)

Comment: How do you know your GPU didn't die?

Comment: (Don't take this as offense because I had the same issue once; I was dumb enough to mess this up, and had similar problems) Are You sure the monitor is plugged into your video cards port? What port are You using? VGA, DVI or HDMI? Did You try moving the video card by pushing it, or taking it out completely and re inserting it into your MB? What is the recognized card at the moment? Is your integrated Radeon card recognized?

Comment: @Louis I tested it in another computer and is ok :)

Comment: @Divin3 don't worry, yes I'm pretty sure, I had used that same video card with another processor and everything was fine, I check the connections of the GPU (PCI, energy) but everything seems to be ok.

Comment: What version of Window are you running? Once you have the Nvidia drivers installed, try uninstalling the AMD Catalyst drivers from the Control Panel.

Comment: Which Windows version are you on? See if you have error/warning messages in the Event Viewer. Also check the Device Manager for any devices that have a yellow icon, and post a screenshot of the contents of the "Sound, video and game controllers" branch.

Comment: Why do you post in this forum if you don't answer our questions ?

Comment: @harrymc I think it's because the question was started with one user account, and then the bounty was placed with a different one (appears to actually be same user tho).  So the user's "bounty" account doesn't get responses (perhaps?)

Comment: @Louis I'm running Ubuntu Gnome, I'll give a try to the drivers!

Comment: @harrymc I'm sorry, I was unable to answer. I'm not a Windows user, but I'll try to get an equivalent

Comment: @harrymc I'm not the one who started the Bounty, but I'm really glad for the attention. I was out of town too, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I have found a couple of things [here that may be helpful](http://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?c=VGA)

> Q: My system failed to recognize the VGA card and show d6 on Dr. Debug.(6/1/2012)
>   A: Since there are some VGA cards with incorrect information in vBIOS
>   (Video BIOS), please contact your VGA card vendor or update
>   motherboard BIOS to latest version from our website:
>   http://www.asrock.com/support/download.asp
>
> Q: When I install ATI HD6670, HD6570, and HD6450 on A75/A55 series
>   motherboards, there is no display output from VGA card. What can I
>   do?(9/1/2011)
>   A: Please update latest BIOS form our website.
>   Download link: http://www.asrock.com/support/download.asp
>   Or, enter BIOS > North Bridge Configuration, and set [Dual Graphics]
>   to [Disabled].

You can always add USB video adapter, works well for most everything but gaming.

I two use [Smart Buy USB Graphics Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TPIRXC) to give me a total of three monitors.

But there are [many to choose from](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=vga%20converter%20to%20usb&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=65450287243&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6291977362061391263&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_31i8sygkxb_b)

Comment: My BIOS is updated =(, is a good idea the USB adapter, although I want the extra video processor

Answer (score 1):

Check :

1. If you have error/warning messages in the Event Viewer.
2. If any devices in the Device Manager have a yellow icon, meaning that are
   missing their driver.

If you want more help from us, post a screenshot of the contents of the "Sound, video and game controllers" branch in the Device Manager.